# VBA excel unable to set value for cells in new worksheet after created

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a new worksheet but I am not unable to set the cell value in the new worksheet in a loop.

```
Dim dueWs As Worksheet

Sub CreateDue()
Dim i, intsal As Integer
Dim firstDue As String

Set dueWs = Sheets.Add
dueWs.Name = "Due date Table"

firstDue = Range("B11").Value
instal = Range("B7").Value

With dueWs
    .Range("A1").Value = "Instalment"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Due date"

    For i = 1 To instal
        .Range("A" & i + 1).Value = i
        .Range("B" & i + 1).Value = firstDue
        firstDue = DateAdd("m", 1, firstDue)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are expecting `Range("A1").Value` to be from `dueWs` then you need a period in front of it so that it works with your `With`.... like this: `.Range("A1").Value` - that qualifies it. Without the period, it ignores your `With` and uses `ActiveSheet` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code by adding the `.`  but still the code inside the for loop is not working. No value is shown in the new table created save for the first row with "Instalment" and "Due date"

Comment: You will want to qualify all of your Ranges. `firstDue` and `instal` are both coming from `ActiveSheet` too. Is that your intent? Put a breakpoint on where the loop starts and check the variables when it stops to see what I mean.

Comment: When you go “Set dueWs = Sheets.Add” then the active sheet becomes “dueWs” and the next “firstDue = Range("B11").Value” statement, using an unreferenced range, will set firstDue to the value of cell B11 of dueWS sheet. And the same goes for “instal” (BTW there’s a typo in its declaration). At least move the “Set dueWS..” and its next line after the two codelines initializating “firstDue” and “instal”, But you’d better declare and use a worksheet object for that one you grab “firstDue” and “instal” values from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create a Sequential List

[image]

- Use `Option Explicit`, it will force you to declare all variables. It would have warned you about the *"intsal"* typo.
- When declaring multiple variables in one line, each has to have an `As` clause or it will be declared `As Variant`, e.g.
  `Dim i As Long, Instal As Long, firstDue As Date`.
- Every **sheet** has a **workbook** so reference it and use it to qualify the sheet with e.g.
  `Set ws = wb.Sheets(...)`.
- Every **range** has a **worksheet** so reference it and use it to qualify the range with e.g.
  `Set rg = ws.Range(...)`.
- Not a big issue, but you could write the last two lines in the loop using a single one:
  `.Range("B" & i + 1).Value = DateAdd("m", i - 1, firstDue)`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateDue()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim unoWs As Worksheet: Set unoWs = wb.Sheets("You know its name")

    Dim Instal As Long, firstDue As Date
    
    With unoWs
        Instal = .Range("B7").Value
        firstDue = .Range("B11").Value
    End With

    Dim dueWs As Worksheet: Set dueWs = Sheets.Add

    Dim i As Long
    
    With dueWs
        .Name = "Due date Table"

        .Range("A1").Value = "Instalment"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Due date"

        For i = 1 To Instal
            .Range("A" & i + 1).Value = i
            .Range("B" & i + 1).Value = firstDue
            firstDue = DateAdd("m", 1, firstDue)
        Next i
    
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    End With

    MsgBox "Due date table created.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Being said what in my comment, you could also avoid looping:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateDue()

    Dim mainSh As Worksheet
        Set mainSh = ActiveSheet ' change 'ActiveSheet' to your actual "main" data worksheet
    
    With Sheets.Add ' add and reference a new sheet
    
        .Name = "Due date Table" ' name the referenced sheet

        .Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Instalment", "Due date") ' write range A1:B1 of the referenced sheet

        With .Range("A2").Resize(mainSh.Range("B7").Value, 2) ' reference a range in the referenced sheet starting from A2 with two columns and as many rows as per "main" sheet cell B7 value
            .Columns(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()-1 ' write the first column of the referenced range"
            .Columns(2).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & mainSh.Name & "!R11C2 +RC[-1]-1" ' write the second column of the referenced range"
            .Value = .Value ' leave only values in the referenced range
        End With
    
    End With
 
End Sub
```